# How can I verify multiple other Adsense publisher-ids on my website

Tags: adsense

I have a website with articles written by myself and others. To reward the other persons for written content for my website I would like to share the Adsense income. I'm thinking about making a standard Adsense code and let the publisher-id rotate.

Can I just use their publisher-id or should the others person verify my website somehow in their Adsense account? And may I just use multiple publisher-ids on my website?

Hopefully someone can tell me what to do. Can't it lead to a ban?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google states "Publishers are permitted to place ad code from different AdSense accounts on the same page as long as the owner of the website has given permission for ads to be placed on their site, and the webpage complies with our program policies.

A publisher will only be credited for clicks and impressions on the ad units associated with their account. Additionally, publishers are responsible for monitoring each webpage upon which their ad code appears to ensure compliance with our policies."

Source: [Google Groups](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/adsense/L_waErm_v-c/itPPwpYOKeQJ)

Comment: Thank you, that makes it clear. Lets say for example that someone is violating the rules or someone clicks for purpose to many times on a ad and the Adsense account gets a ban. Does that affect the other Adsense accounts since the whole website is violating the rules and the others accounts are on this website.

Comment: First it is not that easy to know who is violating. 1- Maybe I want to make you lose the account so I hit too many ads. 2- Maybe you want more earning. 3- Maybe it is someone who likes you so he does that thinking he would help you. Google won't handle it that easy. If Google blocks one account the other would be working but if the site was banned - never heard of that - you both won't have earning from that account.

Comment: Now that Google AdSense reportedly requires an ads.txt whitelist on root, you may also need to add multiple rows into your ads.txt file, like 
    google.com, pub-SOME_ID_1, DIRECT, f08c47fec0942fa0
    google.com, pub-SOME_ID_2, DIRECT, f08c47fec0942fa0

Answer (score 0):

Google's policy on using your own AdSense account on another publisher's website is here: https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1346295?hl=en. You will also need to get the publisher to add you to their ads.txt file, as described by Google here: https://support.google.com/admanager/answer/7441288?hl=en .

Below are highlights from these two sources:

**Ads on the same page or site as another publisher**
If a site is in compliance with our program policies and the company or owner of the site has given you permission to display ads on their site, you may place your ad code on the same page as the other publisher's ad code. You will, however, need to contact your web hosting company or the owner of the site to obtain permission to display ads on their site. Additionally, you will only be credited for clicks and impressions on the ad units associated with your account.

Keep in mind that every publisher is responsible for the content of a site on which their ad code is placed. If a site is found in violation of our policies, we will notify any publisher(s) whose ad code is on the site.

....

Authorized Digital Sellers, or ads.txt, is an IAB initiative to improve transparency in programmatic advertising. Publishers can create their own ads.txt files to identify who is authorized to sell their inventory. The files are publicly available and crawlable by buyers, third-party vendors, and exchanges.